# How to export GRAL plot to JPG?

Tags: java, jpeg, graphics2d

I'm trying to export example [GRAL Pie plot](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/browser/gral-examples/src/main/java/de/erichseifert/gral/examples/pieplot/SimplePiePlot.java) to jpg using:

```
private byte[] getJpg() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bImage.createGraphics();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = new DrawingContext(g2d, DrawingContext.Quality.QUALITY,
            DrawingContext.Target.BITMAP);
    PiePlot plot = getPlot();
    plot.draw(drawingContext);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", baos);
    baos.flush();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

But it renders as black rectangle with some legend information (legend is ok). Who knows the right way to render JPG from GRAL plot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shurely, I found a built'in solution, DrawableWriter. Now the export looks like this:

```
private byte[] getJpg() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bImage.getGraphics();
        DrawingContext context = new DrawingContext(g2d);
        PiePlot plot = getPlot();
        plot.draw(context);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DrawableWriter wr = DrawableWriterFactory.getInstance().get("image/jpeg");
        wr.write(plot, baos, 800, 600);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Thanks to developers! Everything is done already.